# Agregar palabras a String ingresado por consola

Tags: java

hace unos 3 años comencé a estudiar java desde 0, llegue a un nivel principiante y por cuestiones laborales deje de estudiarlo.
Este año comencé a estudiar HTML y CSS y ahora me encuentro con una cuestión, quiero agregarle a ciertos enlaces una redirección a un chat de WhatsApp, esto se hace por medio de su API, funciona de la siguiente manera, a un tag , por ejemplo, en su href le agregas ***https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<número de teléfono>&text=Hola%20quiero%20mas%20informacion***, esto te redirige a la aplicación de WhatsApp y al chat de la persona ingresada, con un mensaje predeterminado... La cosa es que toma mucho tiempo editar el link, ya que, cada palabra nueva que quieras ingresar tenés que ponerle un %20, se me ocurrió la idea de hacer un pequeño algoritmo en java que hiciera esto automáticamente, solo ingresas la frase y te devuelve el link completo digamos, con los respectivos %20 en cada palabra...
No pude hacerlo, logro recorrer la frase por medio de un bucle for, pero hasta ahí llegó el poco conocimiento que me quedo en la memoria, ya que al no practicar periódicamente me olvide todo y estoy empezando desde 0.
Les dejo lo que hice para que se den una idea.

```
public class Convertidor {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("Introduzca una frase");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String res = sc.nextLine();
           for(int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) {
           if(i == ' ' || i =='.' || i == ',' ) {
               
           } 
           
           }   
       }    
   }
```

Elimine todo lo demás del bucle por que no servía, lo deje limpito jaja.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y hagas el [tour] si quieres participar correctamente en la comunidad. Por desgracia, aquí no *trabajamos* para otros. Si tienes un problema concreto, podemos ayudarte a solucionarlo pero *no sé hacer esto, hacedlo por mi* no es un problema, es falta de conocimientos... y la única manera de aprender a programar es *programando*.   Dame un momento y te haré una respuesta que te *ayude a continuar* con lo que llevas si quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dije en el comentario, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo puedes comparar los `char` de un `String` de manera correcta. Por supuesto tendrás que adaptarlo a tu código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Uso un string hardcodeado para ir más rápido
        String res = "Esto es una frase, tiene una coma y un montón de espacios.";
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) {
            /* Este if nunca te va a funcionar, por qué?? Porque i lo estás declarando de tipo int (un número, vaya)
            *  y luego estás intentando comparar si ese entero es igual a un espacio, un punto o una coma...
            * Pero no da error, verdad? Simplemente no funciona, no lo entiendo... eso es porque estás usando comillas
            * simples, y eso es un tipo *char*, cuando comparas un tipo char con un entero, lo que java hace por tí es
            * comparar el VALOR del char en ASCII, por ejemplo, el char 'A' es igual a un int de 65! Por eso no rompe,
            * pero no funciona. Además, tu variable i en realidad empieza valiendo 0 y acabará valiendo lo que sea que
            * mida la frase introducida, no tiene relación con el char que está analizando! Vamos a arreglar esto*/
//            if(i == ' ' || i =='.' || i == ',' ) {
//
//            }
            /* Para empezar, recorreremos el String *mirando* lo que es cada letra, como char! Eso es más fácil que
             * intentar recordar qué valor tiene cada char en ascii! Para ello, guardaré cada letra en la variable letra
             * que es de tipo char. Para hacerlo recurrimos al método charAt() de la clase String
             */
            char letra = res.charAt(i);
            // Ahora que tenemos la letra guardada, vamos a usar el mismo if que tenías tu, pero con letra!
            if(letra == ' ' || letra == '.' || letra == ','){
                System.out.println("He encontrado un espacio, un punto o una coma: '" + letra + "'");
            }else{
                System.out.println("He encontrado otra cosa: '" + letra + "'");
            }
        }
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En los comentarios tienes la explicación de todo y aquí te dejo un [enlace a `charAt()` en la documentación de String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).
Es **MUY** importante para un programador saber buscar en la documentación, te recomiendo que siempre que tengas una duda mires en ella para ver si hay algo que te pueda servir.

Comment: genial, gracias por facilitarme la info!